# TortoiseGit filter for 2 user names

Tags: regex, git, filtering, tortoisegit

I have tried to make a TortoiseGit report for the commit history, 
i made it to exclude 2 users from the logs, i did so for one with:

```
^(.(?!username))*$
```

But i need to exclude an additional user to. How do i filter for 2 strings?

I have already tried with following:

```
^(.(?!username|username1))*$
```

and

```
^(.(?!username))*$|^(.(?!username1))*$
```

ps. Only this filter format works for TortoiseGit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^(?!(?:username1|username2)$).*$` is correct.

Furthermore, please untick other search criteria than `Author`, and remember to tick `Use Regular Expression`

[image]

Note:
Since TortoiseGit 1.8.7.1, you have `Toggle checked filters`

[image: TGit1871]

Answer (score 1):

Could be this

`^(?!(?:username1|username2)$).*$`

or

```
 #  ^(?!username1$)(?!username2$).*$

 ^ 
 (?! username1 $ )
 (?! username2 $ )
 .* 
 $
```